# Laravel Date calculation

Tags: date, laravel, laravel-4

I need to set end_at attribute 30 days from current date. how can i do that in laravel 4.

When I have used bellow code I am getting error saying "Class 'Date' not found"

Please help me to fix this.

```
$sub->end_at   = new Date('+30 days');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return that in the format appropriate for MySQL

```
$sub->end_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+30 days'));
```

Comment: You have so many tags for Laravel, why on earth would you write noncarbon answer?

Comment: While I recommend everyone to use Carbon, this is a more straightforward way of doing this and will also help those who happen to be here who are not using Carbon.  Additionally, there is already a very good answer here that will work just the same which does use Carbon.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Date` class in PHP, there is only a [`DateTime`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class which you could use.

But since you're using Laravel, which uses the [`Carbon`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) library by default, you can use that to handle dates because it has a better API. In your case you can do this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
$sub->end_at = Carbon::now()->addDays(30)->toIso8601String();
```

---

If you're trying to update a Eloquent model, then you can take advantage of Eloquent's integrated date/time column handling. In your model you can add the `dates` property with this value:

```
protected $dates = ['end_at'];
```

and now when assigning a timestamp to the `end_at` column, Laravel will automatically transform and save it to the correct format in your database. So you'll only need to use this:

```
$sub->end_at = Carbon::now()->addDays(30);
```

Comment: i am getting Class 'Carbon' not found. even though i have defined it like this <?php
use Carbon;
class UserController extends BaseController {

Comment: My mistake. It should of had been `use Carbon\Carbon;`.