# Set date input field's min and max 30days date to today

Tags: javascript, laravel

I just have a simple line of code like this:
Is there a way to get disable the following range using the local date?

`<input type='date' min='2023-06-02' max='2023-07-02'></input>`

Is there a simple way to set the min date to "today" and set the max date to +30 days? Or do I have to use Javascript to do this?

example date the can be selected will be todays date to +30 days of the following date

Comment: Either you can use JS or set it from Server side.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Laravel uses the Carbon library, should be easy enough to achieve it with that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29415059/1427878

Answer (score 1):

With javascript, first, you need to get today's date by

```
const [today] = new Date().toISOString().split('T')
```

Then get the max date

```
  const maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 30);
  const [maxDateFormatted] = maxDate.toISOString().split('T');
```

Then set the `min` and `max` attributes.

```
  const dateInput = document.getElementById('myDateInput');
  dateInput.setAttribute('min', today);
  dateInput.setAttribute('max', maxDateFormatted);
```

This is working example

```js
const [today] = new Date().toISOString().split('T');

const maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 30);
const [maxDateFormatted] = maxDate.toISOString().split('T');

const dateInput = document.getElementById('myDateInput');
dateInput.setAttribute('min', today);
dateInput.setAttribute('max', maxDateFormatted);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myDateInput"></input>
```

Comment: @JaybelsonRamos it's better to upvote/accept the answer if it helped you with your question.